# I have downloaded an have Unzipped the glove file in my google colab , but still I'm unable to access it

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, glove

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to access to run this code:

```
word_embedding_matrix = np.load(open("word_embedding_matrix.npy", 'rb'))
```

> FileNotFoundError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 word_embedding_matrix = np.load(open("word_embedding_matrix.npy", 'rb'))
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'word_embedding_matrix.npy'

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for that is you didn't mount your google drive to your notebook. You can do that easily by running the following code in the first cell of your notebook:

```
import os
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
ROOT = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"
os.chdir(ROOT)
```

This code enables your notebook to access your google drive and you can access your GoogleDrive the same as you do with your local disk. So, when you run 
`os.listdir('.')`, you should find `word_embedding_matrix.npy` among the returned items.

Source: [official documentation](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA)